# EcmaScript error in Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, safari, ecmascript-6

I have developed an AngularJs Application. This application is working perfectly fine in **Google Chrome** and **Mozilla Firefox** but when I test this application in **Safari** and **IE-11**. It shows error in console.

Like I am using this code at many places for open the bootstrap modal

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: "dummyTemplate.html",
    controller: "DummyControllerName",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    windowClass: 'popupModal',
    size: 'sm',
    resolve: {
        dummyData: function(){ return object; }
    }
}).result.then(data => { 

});
```

[image]

An other code snippets

```
$rootScope.$on("toastIt", (e, d) => { // <- It show error on this line in IE and Safari
    toaster.pop(d.type || 'success', d.title, d.text);
});
```

I know the reason of this issue is just because of the EcmaScript Support. Internet Explorer and Firefox does't support this.

Any one can suggest me what will be the best way to fix this issue and Enable the support of my AngularJs Application in Safari and IE.

If I will choose the option for modify the code format then there are many places and It will takes too much time. Is there any other better option to fix it?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: *"It shows error in console."* ***What*** error?

Comment: I have updated the question with error Screenshot @T.J.Crowder

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: @str this site tells me about the support. But here I am asking for the solution. Instead of change the whole project code. What will be the best solution?

Comment: Great, but it's the **text** of the error that's needed. (You know, searchability, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're saying that you're getting an error because you've used an arrow function in IE11. And indeed, IE11 doesn't support arrow functions or various other parts of ES2015 and above. (Any version of Firefox from the last several months *does*.)

The solution is to *transpile* your ES2015+ code to ES5 code with a *transpiler* (such as [Babel](http://babeljs.io)). You do this as part of your build step, and deploy the transpiled ES5-compatible code.

Alternately, of course, only use features supported by your target browsers (e.g., don't use arrow functions if targeting IE11).

Answer (score 0):

Your resolve line is missing a closing } - you have this (removed stuff that's not relevant):

```
$modal.open({
  ...
  resolve: {
    smudgedOut: function(){ return response.data
  }
})
```

Should be:

```
$modal.open({
  ...
  resolve: {
    smudgedOut: function() { return response.data; }
  }
})
```

At least, from what you've shown us in the chrome dev tools, that is the issue.

Comment: Its not missing }. Its cropped image. I have post the complete code and I just post the image to show the error message.

Comment: @UFFAN: That's some interesting cropping. :-) Suggest removing it and including the error text as text.

Comment: I have update the error screenshot. Hopefully now there will be no confusion